# Princesses covering an 8x8 chess board

Tags: combinatorics, chess

What is the minimum number of princesses you need to place on an 8x8 chessboard so that every empty square is attacked by at least one princess?

A [princess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_(chess)) is a piece from [fairy chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_chess_piece) that can move like a knight or a bishop.

(Inspired by [recent](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90180/knights-covering-a-9x9-chess-board) [puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90169/knights-covering-a-10x10-chess-board/))

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is the optimal answer with

> 6 princesses.

Shown as knights;

> [image]

Comment: Ah thank you! This problem was driving me insane.

Comment: yes, I tried different forms but there is no other solution then this one, yes mirrors are possible...

Comment: Is `a5` covered ?

Comment: @GoodSp33d yes, by c6

Comment: @Tim If C6 is a queen A5 is still uncovered right ? Its covered if its a knight.

Comment: @GoodSp33d `A princess is a piece from fairy chess that can move like a knight or a bishop.`

Comment: How easy is it to show that there is no solution with only 5 princesses?

Comment: That's the answer I had. Did you do an exhaustive search to check that 5 is not possible?

Comment: @DrXorile  nope, just 5 mins trial and error

Comment: Really a Nice work~

Comment: @TannerSwett, 64 choose 5 is about 7 million. If you're clever you can reduce that by quite a bit for rotations and reflections. It should be possible to brute force it, but I haven't done that. Oray said he didn't either but seemed confident that it was optimal. I don't see any other clever proof although I haven't done more than a few obvious approaches.

Comment: Err not to sound rude, but I am just thinking which Queen will be in attacking range for a pawn placed in either `a5` or `h5` ?

Comment: @GoodSp33d: there are no queens in this puzzle...

Comment: Blimy ! Sorry ! It was probably due to the longs hours ! Lol

Answer (score 9):

I have an arrangement with <s>9</s> 7?  Lot of overlap, but not sure how to improve.

Image of solution:

> [image: 7 princesses]
>  Dots represent knight moves, lines represent bishop moves.

Comment: It's a good start and sets an upper-bound on the solution!

Answer (score 8):

This is a great puzzle that had me really hooked!

Partial answer. I can **almost** do it with 6:

> x are princesses. The only square that remains uncovered is Y. I believe 6 should be possible...
>
> ```
> ........
> ........
> ..x.x...
> ....x...
> .......Y
> ....x...
> ..x.x...
> ........
> ```

Comment: You're right about the 6. Thanks for inspiring this!

Answer (score 8):

Brute force (which, mind you, might be faulty) revealed that

> no solutions with 5 princesses exist

So the accepted answer is probably optimal. Here are, up to mirrorings and rotations, all solutions I found:

> Solution 1
>
> ```
> ........
> .X...X..
> ...X....
> .....X..
> ........
> ..X.X...
> ........
> ........
> ```
>
> Solution 2
>
> ```
> ........
> .X......
> ...XX.X.
> ........
> ........
> ..X.X...
> ........
> ........
> ```
>
> Solution 3
>
> ```
> ........
> ..X.....
> ....XX..
> ........
> ........
> ....XX..
> ..X.....
> ........
> ```
>
> Solution 4
>
> ```
> ........
> ........
> ..XXXX..
> ........
> ........
> ...XX...
> ........
> ........
> ```

Comment: My program gives the same results as yours.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I think we'd all love to see the source code

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Oray's and Arthur's answers, I also found via brute force that

> There is no solution with 5 princesses.

In particular,

> There will always be at least three empty squares that are not
>  attacked by any princess in a 5-princess setup, and there are only 4
>  (or 32, including reflections and rotations) setups for which only
>  three empty squares are not attacked.

The (as close to optimal but still failing) setups:

> [image]

Code (R):

```
#######
# Set up chessboard
# reading as book, numbers 1-64
#######
xs <- rep(1:8, times=8)
ys <- rep(1:8, each=8)

get_princess_moves <- function(ind){
  x <- xs[ind]
  y <- ys[ind]

  ### Bishop-like moves (includes self)
  ## Up-right/down-left diagonals
  moves <- c(unlist(mapply(function(xcand, ycand){
    which(xs == xcand & ys == ycand)
  }, x + (-7:7), y + (-7:7))))
  ## Up-left/down-right diagonals
  moves <- c(moves, unlist(mapply(function(xcand, ycand){
    which(xs == xcand & ys == ycand)
  }, x - (-7:7), y + (-7:7))))
  ### Knight-like moves: each combination of +/- 2 in one direction and +/- 1 in the other direction
  moves <- c(moves, unlist(mapply(function(xcand, ycand){
    which(xs == xcand & ys == ycand)
  }, x + c(2,2,-2,-2,1,1,-1,-1), y + c(1,-1,1,-1,2,-2,2,-2))))

  unique(moves)
}

moves_list <- lapply(1:64, get_princess_moves)

n_covered5 <- combn(64, 5, function(inds)length(unique(unlist(moves_list[inds]))))

max_cover5 <- max(n_covered5)

max_inds5 <- which(n_covered5 == max_cover5)

combn(64,5)[,max_inds5]
```

Comment: How long does that take to run? Thanks for posting. Great answer

Comment: It takes about 2 minutes on my machine (the vast majority due to calculating the n_covered5 variable).

Comment: @DrXorile (also for Brent, and anyone else interested) Here is some [C code](https://onlinegdb.com/BJawGmBtS) that runs in about one second if compiled locally. I can improve readability if you like.