# 21 knights covering a 11x11 chess board

Tags: combinatorics, chess, optimization

Can you place 21 knights on a 11x11 chess board, such that every empty cell is under attack? Good luck!

Here is a similar question for 10x10: [Knights covering a 10x10 chess board](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90169/knights-covering-a-10x10-chess-board)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Define a graph with one node per cell and an edge for each pair of cells that are a knight's move away from each other.  For node $i\in N$, let $N_i \subset N$ be the neighbors of $i$, and let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether node $i$ is selected.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i\in N} x_i$ subject to
$$x_i + \sum_{j\in N_i} x_j \ge 1 \quad \text{for $i\in N$}.$$
The constraint enforces that either node $i$ or one of its neighbors is selected.

Here's one optimal solution:

> ```
>   . . . . . . . . . . .
>   . . X . . . . . X . .
>   . X X X . . X X X X .
>   . . . . . . . . . . .
>   . . . . X . . . . . .
>   . . . . . . . . . . .
>   . . X . . . . . . . .
>   . . X . X . . . X X .
>   . . X . . . . . X X .
>   . . X . X . . X . . .
>   . . . . . . . . . . .
> ```

The minimum such *domination number* for an $n \times n$ board is in [OEIS A006075](https://oeis.org/A006075).

Comment: How do you actually minimaze that? Do you use some program?

Comment: Yes, @Greedoid I used the [MILP solver](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=v_008&docsetId=casmopt&docsetTarget=casmopt_milpsolver_toc.htm&locale=en) in SAS.

Comment: As always, excellent work Rob!

Comment: Any way, are those computations doable by hand (in reasonable time)?

Comment: @Greedoid There are 121 variables, 121 constraints, and 841 constraint coefficients.  Tiny for a MILP solver, but nothing I'd want to do by hand.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but do you have any combinatorial problem which could be done by ILP by hand. :) I would realy like to try it to get a filling what is all about it.

Comment: A Google search for *integer linear programming branch and bound* yields several small examples in videos or slides.

Answer (score 5):

@RobPratt's answer is correct. Here are the alternative arrangements I've found, all of which are only slightly different from each other.

> [image]
>  
>  
>  Picking exactly one white knight from each color group will lead to a valid arrangement, giving a total of $5 \cdot 5 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 8 = 100$ arrangements unique up to reflection and rotation.

Comment: This matches the count of inequivalent solutions in https://oeis.org/A006076

Comment: Are you sure the picture is correct? Last row, third column - this field is only attacked by one of the blue knights and by no black one.

Comment: @daw Well spotted. Same for third row, first and fifth columns

Comment: @daw Thanks for pointing that out! I got one of the "volatile" knight positions wrong. Fix incoming :)

Comment: @Zoir you mean (4,8) and (4,10) right? Those knights are of no use

Comment: @xhienne Yes, the blue group should cover (3,11) but it covered (2,9) in the original solution. Should be fixed now :)

Comment: @Zoie. There is still a problem with the third row (see my comment above). Knight in (3,2) is necessary.

Comment: Actually, your knight in (3,11) does not any useful purpose

Comment: @xhienne A knight in (3,11) is useful because it occupies (3,11), thus covering it. (it isn't covered by any black knight) As for the problem with the red group, still trying to figure that out :)

Comment: The problem has been fixed now.

Comment: Very nice! Now we have all the solutions.